# ECM embedding language when it shouldn't

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-ecm

Sitecore 6.6 rev 130214.  ECM 2.0 rev. 130123

I'm encountering a number of 404 errors when trying to view the "Messages" and "Reports" links in the left-hand navigation of ECM. (Links like "Recently Dispatched", "Search Messages", "Messages in Progress", etc)

What I've found is that the links being generated are embedding the language.  In my case, the URL generated includes "en" in the path.  When this is included I get a 404 when clicking on them.  When I remove the "en" from the path, the page renders normally.

Not working:

```
http://myserver/en/speak/EmailCampaign/Messages/RecentlyDispatched
```

Working:

```
http://myserver/speak/EmailCampaign/Messages/RecentlyDispatched
```

I've got "languageEmbedding" set to "never" in my web.config, but it looks like ECM/Speak may not be taking this into account.

Before I take this to support, has anyone else seen this?  Feels like a bug to me.

Thanks!

Craig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the same problem and contacted sitecore support. They registered this as a bug and send us a hotfix, but this bug has now been fixed in ECM 2.1 rev.130529.

You can check the release notes here (ref.number 386058): http://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/ECM/ECM%202,-d-,1/Release%20Notes.aspx
regards,
Vicent